# How can I map my large yet sparse enum to array indices in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum class, now I want to turn them into array, so that any given enum I could return the corresponding object like below:

```
PeopleInfo fetch(enum e) {
    return arr[e];
}
```

Sounds easy, 1-1 mapping would do the trick, but today my enum is relative large and sparse like

```
enum class People: {
    American_start = 0x0,
    John,
    Aaron, 
    ...
    Asian_start = 0x10000,
    Yen_Huan,
    Kang_Hsuan,
    European_start = 0x20000,
    ...
}
```

As you can see, in order to preserve the space for additional people to join in the future, these enum apparently cannot use 1-1 mapping here, that's just a total waste of memory, what I need is an array with size of all people listed, so I can get the info I want

Does anybody has good idea how to do so?

Comment: `std::unordered_map` might be good enough since you already mention the keyword `map`.

Comment: You could use a bunch of `if` statements to determine which block the enum falls into, then use a 1:1 mapping array within each block.

Comment: @LouisGo sorry forgot to emphasize that memory is another point should be taken into consider. unordered_map would consume a lot of memories as well. I want an array that has exact size of number of people listed

Comment: Then using `std::unordered_map::reserve` for exact size should be fine (presume load factor is set to 1)? Since you know the size in compilation time.

Comment: Keep business data and database keys completely separate. This is also applicable here. If John is American, that's business data. It shouldn't be a part of his unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index that isn't sparse, so that you can use an array that doesn't have any holes in it.

```
PeopleInfo fetch(enum e) {
    index = e;
    if (index >= European_start)
        index -= European_start - Asian_end;
    if (index >= Asian_start)
        index -= Asian_start - American_end;
    if (index >= American_start)
        index -= American_start;
    return arr[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, Mark, but not offensive, what if we categorize people by countries instead of continents, your if...else statement would be rangy, which is hard to maintain

Comment: @Shih-ChanHuang I was just going by what you put in the question.  Of course if your enumeration has more holes in it, there will be more work to remove the holes.  That's a design compromise you have to consider.  I was trying to optimize your implied goal of minimizing the space required.

Comment: @Shih-ChanHuang: I suggest to take a step back and reconsider your original design. Why do you want a sparse enum for categorization? Why not a data structure holding `continent` and `country`?  Giving an enum categorization functionality seems like breaking SRP. It does more than enumeration. And yes, it might be [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/698534)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2D-array where the columns are the continents. Then you can identify the continent by the upper bytes and objects by the lower bytes.

```
SomeObject arr[NUMBER_OF_CONTINENTS][MAX_NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS];
PeopleInfo fetch(enum e) {
    return arr[e >> 16][e & 0xffff];
}
```

Note: You might waste some memory, when one continent has a lot more objects than the others.